# Github remote Branch and Local Git Repo

Tags: git, github, merge, branch, pull

Added a new Branch to my Github, but can't find a way to have my local repo "know" about it. I have my local repo using the master branch (the only one it knows about), and it is several commits ahead of the other new remote branch it is not aware of. I want to make my local git aware of this new branch, and then push those commits to the new remote branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say that your remote is called `origin` (the default) and the branch is called `feature1`. Then first of all you must do a pull (or a fetch).

```
git pull
```

This will bring down information to your local repository about the branch. The output of the command should include something like this

```
 * [new branch]      feature1   -> origin/feature1
```

After that you do

```
git checkout feature1
```

This should create a local branch called feature1 that will track the remote branch, so that you can pull and push to the corresponding remote. The output should look like this

```
Branch feature1 set up to track remote branch feature1 from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'feature1'
```

If that fails for some reason, or you want to be really explicit about it, you can instead do

```
git checkout --track origin/feature1
```